# django redirect to home page after logging out

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm trying to redirect to the home page after logging out by using django's `logout_then_login` function describe at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/ but I think I'm not passing the url in correctly (I'm fairly new to django)

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

**Homepage URL**

```
url(r'^$', 'myfitgames.views.home', name='home'),
```

**Logout URL**

```
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login(request,"/")', name='logout'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument should be name of the view or a function.

Try following (Using a lambda as a function):

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout_then_login

url(r'^accounts/logout/$', lambda request: logout_then_login(request, "/"), name='logout'),
```

Comment: Worked great! I appreciate the feedback.